# Get the maximum value out of an complex class

Tags: c#

I have the following class:

```
class Seller
{
    private string sellerName;
    private decimal price;
}
~propreties for SellerName and Price goes here~
```

I also have a list of sellers:

```
list<Seller> s = new list<Seller>();
```

How can I get the maximum value of `price` out of all the sellers?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use linq like this:

```
var max = s.Select(o => o.Price).Max();
//or this
var max = s.Max(o => o.Price);
```

For this to work though, `price` needs to be `public` so it's accessible.

You can also get the seller with the maximum price, like this:

```
var maxPriceSeller = s.OrderByDescending(o => o.Price).First();
```

(`Price` being the property for your `price` field)

Comment: Do I have to use the property or the data member itself?

Comment: Just a note, `Max()` is part of the `System.Linq` namespace.

Comment: @iTayb - Either one, a property or a field works, as long as it's public, updated the examples to use your properties, something like `public double Price { get; set; }` or example.

Comment: Those two statements return the same thing i.e. an int representing the max price. You won't get the seller using the second statement.

Comment: @Simon - Good catch, I forgot it's `Func<T, U>`, it's updated now.